# How do i create multi-field table relationships using vba?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a data entry program for field (no network - marine research) use.  When the user gets back to the office they submit the data to the server for import into the master sql database. It then creates an empty access database file and exports the tables (DoCmd.TransferDatabase) so the user has a local copy for their offsite research purposes. What I am trying to do is recreate the table relationships in the new data file using DAO.Database.CreateRelation().  It works until I get to a table that needs two fields as a PK or FK.

```
Table1                    Table2                    Table3
SampleNumber  1--------M  SampleNumber  1--------M  SampleNumber
.                         LineNumber    1--------M  LineNumber
.                         .                         HookNumber
.                         .                         .
.                         .                         .

Table1_PK -> SampleNumber
Table2_PK -> SampleNumber+LineNumber
Table3_PK -> SampleNumber+LineNumber+HookNumber
```

When I use this in my function:

```
Set newRelation = db.CreateRelation(relationUniqueName, _
                        primaryTableName, foreignTableName, relAttr)
```

it returns an error:

```
3001: Invalid argument.
```

But only when I try to create the above relationships.  All other relationships create correctly.

Is there a way to do this, or should I just not worry about it and let them figure it out?

Comment: That table layout seems illogical to me. Why two tables with the same keys (table 2 and table 3) linking through each other instead of just to the first? I'm sure I'm missing something here, but I don't understand what you're after. Can we see more of the data model?

Comment: Table 1 identifies the trip, table 2 identifies a line on that trip (2 or 3), table three identifies hooks (10) on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to create a Relationship like this:

[image: Relationships.png]

then you should be able to do it like this:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rel As DAO.Relation, fld As DAO.Field
Set cdb = CurrentDb

Set rel = cdb.CreateRelation("Table2Table3", "Table2", "Table3")

Set fld = New DAO.Field
fld.Name = "SampleNumber"
fld.ForeignName = "SampleNumber"
rel.Fields.Append fld

Set fld = New DAO.Field
fld.Name = "LineNumber"
fld.ForeignName = "LineNumber"
rel.Fields.Append fld

cdb.Relations.Append rel

Set fld = Nothing
Set rel = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  This fixed my problem of creating the multi-field relation.  The other problem I had was the relationship name was too long - over 64 characters.  Once I limited it to 64 or less in my function it worked great.